# Biblatex: How do I include links in the reference list?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, links, hyperlink

I need some help with my reference list using biblatex. Most papers I read have links to websites included in the reference itself without printing the actual link (see first picture). This makes the reference list more neat and tidy compared to what I have now (figure 2). I could not find the necessary settings for this to work when I googled the problem, any ideas on how to do this?

Essentially what I want to do is to remove DOI and "Available"-link and use the rest of the text as a large link.

Thanks in advance.

[image: What I want.]

[image: What I have.]

Comment: Is this for a thesis? A few thoughts: When it is printed, it’s more difficult to find the reference when it is not shown. On the other hand, your style adds a lot of redundant information. The DOI and the URL link to the same place (which is obviously online). And you probably won’t cite any source that is not available. I would suggest to only print the DOI and remove the "https://doi.org/"-part from the printed link. Saves you almost two lines while making it easy to find the source either way. Changing the URL front from monospace to propotional reduces the size even further.